# Standard for storing external IDs in LDAP (like 'login with Facebook')

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is there a standard for storing IDs of external ID providers in LDAP?
Or should I create my own attributes for storing this information.

This is to store use user ID for the 'Login with Google' or 'Login with Facebook' functionality.

Comment: You should generally use existing ObjectCLasses/attributes if you can. But it all depends on what information you are storing.

Comment: @jwilleke that kind of is the point of my question, I'm looking for information on existing ObjectClasses and attributes for storing such information.

Comment: Look at: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2798 I am sure there is some attributes you can use for just a user ID. Are there any secrets to be stored?